# Using GPIOs within a kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel-module

i am quiet new at writing kernel drivers and there is something bothering me a lot. It would be great if you could kcik me into the right direction.

I am writing a module for a device, that has to be powered via putting a GPIO to HIGH-State.

1. In *Documentation/gpio/** are texts, which say i should use the *new     descriptor-based interface* of the *GPIO Framework*. But how to use it?
   When i make an include like *#include* 
   it compiles and i can run the driver. But using *gpiod_get(...)* just returns *fffffffffffffffe*. It makes sense somehow, as the implentation of that function within *linux/gpio/consumer.h* is

> static inline struct gpio_desc *__must_check gpiod_get(struct device
>   *dev,           const char *con_id,enum gpiod_flags flags){
>           return ERR_PTR(-ENOSYS);
>       }

The implementation of the function exists in *drivers/gpio/devres.c* as well. How can i use that one?

It looks to me as i am not supposed to use that implementation.

I hope you can help me as it is getting really irritating.

Comment: If you look into `linux/gpio/consumer.h`, it has **two declarations** of `gpiod_get` function: the first one is simple declaration, and the second one is declaration with definition. The first one corresponds to `CONFIG_GPIOLIB` configuration option enabled, and has usefull implementation in `drivers/gpio/devres.c`. The second one corresponds to the disabled option, and its implementation means just "not implemented". So you need to have `CONFIG_GPIOLIB` option enabled for use GPIO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You definitly encourage me to re-think my build-system, as  *CONFIG_GPIOLIB* **is** set in my kernel defconfig. But probably not in my out-of-tree sources... I'll tell you about the outcome when i got so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out it was just necessary to include the file *gpio/gpiolib* as well which delivers additional definitions.